# How to intercept connection event in Grails with MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, grails, groovy

I'm using grails 4 to develop my backend, and I want to control how connections to my MongoDb is logged. Right now, nothing is logged (at least not unless the connection fails). There seems to be a lot going on under the hood, and the whole process of connecting to my database is very much hidden. It seems like the main bean that takes care of this is called `mongoDatastore`, but is there an easy way to, for example, register a listener for connection events on this bean? Or do I have to extend `MongoDatastore` and register my own bean?

I also had an idea of using the `applicationContext` to fetch the bean, and from there somehow register an event listener, but I don't know when or where in the initialization phase I would to that.

Answer (score 0):

All MongoDB 4.4-compatible drivers publish [CMAP events](https://docs.mongodb.com/ruby-driver/master/tutorials/ruby-driver-monitoring/#connection-pool-and-connection-monitoring) that the application can subscribe to. These tell you when individual connections are made and closed as well as pool behavior.

Comment: Hmm okay thanks. I'm really not sure when or how I can subscribe to these events in my grails app though...

Comment: Most likely you will need to request this directly from the driver.